# Help me identify a resistor

Tags: resistors, identification, component-values

I don't see what it is. I think it is a 56 Ω resistor. Is that correct?

[image: resistor]

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Unsolder and measure it?

Comment: I do it, but it is dead

Comment: Bummer. 56 ohm would be my guess too.

Comment: Yes, correct. From the position (looks like a series gate resistor) probably a few more bad parts are on  your board

Comment: I have replaced the resistor 56ohm and the K3067, but the power block is still dead...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it appears to be a 56 Ω resistor.